# Karate - Is it possible to use 1st line of data in csv file in one file and the 2nd line of data in another feature file

Tags: csv, karate

In my .csv file, I have the list of firstName and lastName. I want to use first entry in one feature file and the 2nd entry in another feature file. Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps: https://github.com/intuit/karate#calling-other-feature-files - note that you can "pass data" to other feature files.

And note that when you read a CSV file, you get JSON: https://github.com/intuit/karate#csv-files

If that does not help - then the answer is - no it is not possible to do that !